# using nant to run a bat file in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, nant

I have created a batch file for ex(ex.bat)

Is it possible to run batch file through nant c#.net code

Problem 1: i need to create pass the arguments to that xml file generated through ant

problem 2: i need to access through c# .net code

Waiting for your valuable comments

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631592/calling-batch-files-inside-nant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
< target name="run-command">
   < exec program="ConsoleTest.exe" basedir="${test.dir}">
     < arg value="-cp" />
   < /exec>
 < /target>
```

http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html

from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/663238/649524)

Comment: @thilak i have a generated the xml file which you gave ! but i need to pass arguments through c# code .net